# What iptables rules should I use in order for my Discourse app to be able to use Mandrill?

Tags: iptables, discourse

I am currently trying to secure a little my server before its release to the world. For now, there is just a Discourse instance running, that uses Mandrill as email smtp server.

There is an nginx server in front of that Discourse.

With no iptables rules, everything works fine. When I apply my rules, it brokes. I am still able to reach the Discourse and even send posts and everything, expect sending email.

With `./launcher mailtest app`, it works. The Discourse error, however, is the following : `ERREUR - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known`.

I really try to find out myself what I should use. But I couldn't.
First, I was thinking a simple `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT` was enough, but I was proved the contrary.

Some other inputs :

```
iptables -F
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
```

I set Discourse to use port 587 of Mandrill.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, so I just released... This is not the right SE forum for that question. I'm sorry for that.

However, since I finally found a solution (it's always when you post your question that the question hits you in the face), let me share it.

I was missing a FORWARD rule between docker0 and eth0.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i docker0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

Sorry for the inconvenient.